# Perform arithmetic operation mainly subtraction and division over a pandas series on null values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Simply i want when i subtract/division operation with null value it will give the value(digit).Ex - 3/np.nan = 3 or 2-np.nan = 2.

By using np.nansum and np.nanprod i have handled addition and multiplication,but dont know how will i do operation for subtraction and division.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,4],"b":[1,2,np.nan,np.nan]})
df
Out[6]: 
   a    b    c=a-b  d=a/b
0  1  1.0  0.0      1.0
1  2  2.0  0.0      1.0
2  3  NaN  3.0      3.0
3  4  NaN  4.0      4.0
```

Above i mention that actually what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
#Use fill value of 0 for subtraction operation    
df['c']=df.a.sub(df.b,fill_value=0)

#Use fill value of 1 for division operation 
df['d']=df.a.div(df.b,fill_value=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC using `sub` with `fill_value`

```
df.a.sub(df.b,fill_value=0)
Out[251]: 
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
dtype: float64
```